# Deploy a local file in MSVC 2019 without recompile

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

Running Win 10, MSVC 2019 community edition with latest updates.
I am trying to deploy a local config file from the project directories - where it is under version control - to a local directory, but without being forced to run a recompile.

I have added the file to the project as a resource file
set its properties as 'Copy file'
set the destination directories to the desired config directory - $(APPDATA)$(ProjectName)
set 'Treat destination files as content' -> Yes

Whether I modify the file or not, when the project is recompiled, the file is copied, as expected.

What I am looking for is a way to have the file copied without a recompile, simply by restarting the debugger, whether it has been modified or not. But, I must force a recompile, if only by adding or removing a space somewhere in the code - a bit dangerous.

What I need is a build step initiated by or dependent on the debugger, not the compiler.
I realize there is the 'Custom Build Step' option, but I have not been able to identify a suitable candidate in either the 'Execute Before' or Execute After' dropdowns.